# Hours between two times in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am making an app that will allow users to book appointments. However, I am stuck because I have no idea how to go about finding a salon's active hours.

To start, I have created a Firebase document to hold hours (open to close), like so:

```
monday: [ "9:30am", "5:30pm" ]
```

Parsing the hours is not an issue, however, how would I go about generating a list of hours. For example, print out a list like:

```
9:30am, 10:30am, 11:30am, 12:30pm, 1:30pm, 2:30pm, 3:30pm, 4:30pm.
```

And for busier salons, print out of list of hours at 30 minute intervals:

```
9:30am, 10:00am, 10:30am, etc.
```

I don't know if this makes any sense, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
void main() {
  
  DateTime _currentDate = DateTime(1990,1,1,9,30);
  
  String _shiftedDate="";
  
  List<String> _workingTimeSlot = [];
  
  
  while(_shiftedDate != "17:30"){
    
    _shiftedDate = "${_currentDate.hour}:${_currentDate.minute}";
    _workingTimeSlot.add(_shiftedDate);
    _currentDate =  _currentDate.add(Duration(minutes:30));
        
  }
    print(_workingTimeSlot);

}
```

But you should parse those Strings first and compare the actual DateTime object not the String. And use DateFormatter instead. This is just an example